# Multi Key Hotkeys in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, hotkeys, vb.net-2010

I've written a simple WAV player in VB 2010 - a Windows Form App with no menus.  I'm trying to create a hotkey, like CTRL-D that would make a text box visible.  Typing the correct password in the box will expand the form and show some Administrative functions.  I'm having issues creating the hotkey with more than one key.

I've got the following code, but it does not work.  I do have KeyPreview set to True.

```
Private Sub _KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        txtPWD.Visible = True
```

I've also tried

```
If e.Keycode = Keys.ControlKey & e.KeyCode = Keys.D
```

and many other variations including changing to ALT and SHIFT but nothing seems to work.  If I remove one of the Keys, it works just fine.  Where am I getting this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for Modifierkeys:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys.aspx

Comment: You are my hero!  Works perfectly...Thank you.