# Windows form hotkeys

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to use hotkeys on a form to hide/show a textbox, tried many ways and after reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438410/multi-key-hotkeys-in-vb-2010), I did this:

```
If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.B Then
    If TextBox1.Visible = True Then
        TextBox1.Visible = False
    Else
        TextBox1.Visible = True
    End If
```

and:

```
If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.B Then
    If TextBox1.Visible = True Then
        TextBox1.Hide()
    Else
        TextBox1.Hide()
    End If
End If
```

but still not working.. help me, please

Comment: How can `Control.ModifierKeys` ever equal `Keys.B`? Modifier keys are Ctrl, Shift and Alt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set the forms property

```
KeyPreview = True
```

Then use the forms KeyDown event

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.B Then TextBox1.Visible = Not TextBox1.Visible
    End Sub
```

If you want to use an ALT or other combination you need to check the modifiers too

```
  Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If CBool(e.Modifiers And Keys.Alt) AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.B Then TextBox1.Visible = Not TextBox1.Visible
  End Sub
```

If you want to do lots of them then use a select case statement

```
  Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        Select Case e.KeyCode
           case  Keys.B : TextBox1.Visible = Not TextBox1.Visible
           'etc
        End Select
  End Sub
```

Comment: Good to hear, please. remember to accept the answer. IF you need to check combinations of modifier and can't figure it out, please don't hesitate to ask.